# Como crear un índice de un campo de tipo Datetime pero descartando la hora? (o sea usar solo el DATE)SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tengo que hacer un índice de un campo que es de tipo `datetime`  (`1900-01-01 00:00:00`), pero descartando la hora `1900-01-01`.

Pero, por lo visto, no acepta poner `convert`, `format` o `cast` en el índice. Ya probé de todo. ¿Alguna recomendación?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_pasaje_FechaHora ON dbo.Pasaje (convert(date,FechaEmision))
```

Índice de valores únicos, que requieren de ordenamiento físico de las filas de la tabla Pasaje en base a las columnas FechaEmision (pero solo la fecha sin la hora). Requerimiento: No puedo agregar otra columna ni modificar la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una columna calculada, que tenga solamente la parte de la fecha, y crear el índice o un constraint `unique` sobre esta columna, por ejemplo, esta sentencia creará correctamente la tabla, el constraint `unique` y su correspondiente `unique index`.

```
create table PruebaDT (
    idPrueba       int not null identity (1, 1) primary key
  , Fecha          datetime not null
  , SoloFecha as cast(Fecha as Date)
  , constraint UQ_PruebaDTFecha unique (SoloFecha)
);
```

La tabla resultante, vista en el SSMS:

[image: tabla de prueba]

Comment: Entiendo tu recomendación, pero lo que tengo es un ejercicio de practica de la Universidad, que dice asi:  Índice de valores únicos, que requieren de ordenamiento físico de las 
  filas de la tabla Pasaje en base a las columnas FechaEmision
   (pero solo la fecha sin la hora)... No nos dice que agregemos mas columnas a la tabla

Comment: Información que, por supuesto, omitiste en la pregunta. Como sea, no veo dónde el requerimiento dice que no se puede crear una columna calculada para lograrlo.

Comment: Lo siento, realmente aun no uso mucho esta plataforma. lo arreglare.